# unable to scp files from remote to local when logged in remote

Tags: ssh, scp

I am trying to scp from remote to my local. I am already logged on my remote host. I tried this

```
scp -r hw8/ peke:~/Desktop/
ssh: Could not resolve hostname peke: Name or service not known
```

my local computer name is peke, which I can see from bash terminal.

however, I logged out of my remote and then did scp from remote host to local and it worked fine.
I am trying to figure why the above method failed. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your hostname to FQDN hostname like srv.hostname.com and then try it with that hostname.

Before using the FQDN hostname also make sure that your local host is accessible from remote host by pinging your hostname from remote host.

Replace hostname with your hostname

> ping hostname

if not then try with your IP.